# How to update twitter status with image using image url in tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

This is the code I've used,

```
#Twitter credentials
access_token = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'access_token')
access_token_secret = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'access_token_secret')
consumer_key = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'consumer_key')
consumer_secret = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'consumer_secret')

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = API(auth)

img = "http://animalia-life.com/data_images/bird/bird1.jpg"
api.update_with_media(img, status="Nice one")
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
No such file or directory
```

I know that I have to use a file from the local directory with the above command. Is there a way to use a URL while using update_with_media ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need use a local file to upload via tweepy. I would suggest using a library like `requests` to download the file first.

```
import requests
import os


def twitter_api():
    access_token = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'access_token')
    access_token_secret = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'access_token_secret')
    consumer_key = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'consumer_key')
    consumer_secret = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'consumer_secret')

    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = API(auth)
    return api


def tweet_image(url, message):
    api = twitter_api()
    filename = 'temp.jpg'
    request = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as image:
            for chunk in request:
                image.write(chunk)

        api.update_with_media(filename, status=message)
        os.remove(filename)
    else:
        print("Unable to download image")


url = "http://animalia-life.com/data_images/bird/bird1.jpg"
message = "Nice one"
tweet_image(url, message)
```

Comment: Works fine. Is there any way to remove the temporary downloaded file once the operation is done.

Comment: Yep! just use `os.remove(filename)`. I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Twython Release 3.4.0

```
photo = open('/path/to/file/image.jpg', 'rb')
response = twitter.upload_media(media=photo)
twitter.update_status(status='Checkout this cool image!', media_ids=[response['media_id']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just include the link in a status update?

```
img = "http://animalia-life.com/data_images/bird/bird1.jpg"
api.status(status="%s Nice one" % img)
```

Comment: Tried it too. Twitter just shows it as a plain text

Comment: Note: URLs will count against your tweet character limit